# start-stop-daemon alway returns success

Tags: bash, output, daemon

I have the following piece of code in a BASH script:

```
 start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background \
    --startas /bin/bash -- -c "$CMD; exec echo $?> $FILE"
```

where `CMD` is some command string and `FILE` is an output file location. For some reason though, the output in `FILE` is always 0, even when it should give a different number (1 for error, etc).

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$?` gets expanded in the context of the current shell together with `$CMD` and `$FILE`.

To fix this you'll have to escape it like `\$?`, i.e.

```
...  /bin/bash -c "$CMD; exec echo \$? >$FILE"
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the source of the problem! Thank a lot, this has been driving me and many other people nuts!

Answer (score 0):

exec echo $? this will print 0 if your last command was run successfully. and that is why it prints 0 in file. what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Editted question. If it fails, the output should be a 1, etc.

Comment: Did you try running this command " start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background \
    --startas /bin/bash -- -c "$CMD;" and then run echo $? to see what it comes. if your first command gets run then it would be 0. otherwise it would be non zero.

Comment: That doesn't give the exit code of the CMD, that gives the exit code of start-stop-daemon. That is, it returns 0 if it was able to successfully attempt the commands, but that says nothing about if the commands themselves actually worked.